# Code Analysis as Warning Locally but Error on TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild, code-analysis

I'd like Code Analysis violations to show up as warnings locally (so that devs can still F5 run even if there are CA violations), but as Errors in the TFS Build (more specifically I'd like the build to fail).

I still want to maintain the list of rules I care about in one place though, so I don't want to have to create separate ruleset files for local/TFS.

Any ideas for how I could configure this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a msbuild parameter on the build definition.  I thinks its /p:CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors=true

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!  For anybody else interested, you can see the full list of CodeAnalysis-specific MSBuild properties available to set, by opening the file C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets